# Where to do JWT expiration with Node.js and jsonwebtoken?

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, token

I am creating a web application based on MEAN and I have the following question:

Where is it better to put a token (JWT) expiration? Right now what I am doing is to create a token without expiration and in the client, I created a cookie with that token and 10 minutes of expiration.

In that cookie, I add 10 minutes in every request I make. If the user is inactive for 10 minutes that cookie expires and the request is made without a token.

Comment: why wouldn't you keep it in the token itself?

Comment: Read @Joe Clay´s answer to see why you shouldn´t follow the direction of having a JWT with no expiration and rely on cookie to determines it. 
You can store your JWT on localStorage, and if you end up with the need of having the token stored on cookies, set it as a HttpOnly at least (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Chrome:

> F12 ➡️ Application tab ➡️ Cookies ➡️ Copy and paste token into a REST client like Postman

Whoops, I just got an everlasting token for your API!

In other words, as you suspected, this isn't a good way of doing things. The expiration should be in the token's payload - that way, you can verify nobody has altered it, as it'll be signed with your server secret value.

The Node JWT library actually [has this functionality built-in](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim):

```
jwt.sign({
  // 1 hour expiration
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60),
  data: 'foobar'
}, 'secret');
```

This isn't to say that you can't/shouldn't *also* use cookie expiration with your tokens, but relying on it alone isn't secure.

Comment: Could it refresh the expiration of that token? Increase expiration? Or would it have to generate a new token before it expires?

Comment: @elcabezon: [This article](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JoeClay Are the JSON Web Signature (JWS) and JSON Web Encryption (JWE) still current standard in 2020? The article that you reference includes them.